# Microsoft Graph Calendar ErrorInternalServerError: "IANA time zones are not supported..."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

When making certain `updateCalEvent` PATCH requests to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events` with the `America/Los_Angeles` timeZone, I'm getting an ErrorInternalServerError:

`"IANA time zones are not supported. REST APIs for this mailbox are currently in preview. You can find more information about the preview REST APIs at https://dev.outlook.com/."`

What does this generally mean? As in, does ErrorInternalServerError mean this is on Microsoft's end, or does the error message mean the timezone is invalid?

Note: The Graph API website [directs users to SO](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/support) to ask any questions about usage.

Comment: I am facing same error for Calendar create and update. see this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/085fb37f-5ef5-4a3f-8ff6-02ae6effcba8/errorinternalservererror-when-creating-calendar-using-graph-api?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment&prof=required

Answer (score -1):

You have to use Windows time-zones for the Graph instead of the IANA time zones. To get an overview of the supported timezones you get request them from the Graph.